# how to have a different wallpaper for different virtual desktops

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, virtual-desktop

I'm running Ubuntu Karmic Koala with gnome and have the standard two virtual desktops setup.

I want to setup the background so that it either spans the two virtual desktops like a dual monitor setup or set it up to have different wall papers for each desktop, either way I can get the effect that I want.  How do I do this?

Please keep in mind, I'm a newbie to linux, and so details are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an illustrated tutorial:

**[Different wallpapers on each workspace in ubuntu](http://ubuntuguide.net/different-wallpapers-on-each-workspace-in-ubuntu)**

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that Compiz can do that. It's a desktop manager with a bunch of flashy/useful features. Very popular, and should be easy to get from the package manager/software center. Compiz is worth a poke around, it's fairly intuitive, no command line necessary.